# ios - can not figure out why list of items displays value of the first item in first and last spots when adding new item

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have a list of strings that I fetch from a remote database, and they display fine. Then when I add a string, that new string is added to the database fine, but when it comes time to display it on the screen, it for some reason displays the value of the first item in both, the first and last items.

Here is what I am doing:

```
// CREATING EACH CELL IN THE LIST
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"business";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [cellTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    // CLOSE THE SPINNER
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    // return the cell for the table view
    return cell;
}
```

and when the data is retrieved from the database, here is what I do:

```
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                if(!error){
                    [self loadTitleStrings];
                }

                [self.itemList reloadData];
            });
```

And here is the loadTitleStrings that is called

```
-(void)loadTitleStrings
{
    if(!standardUserDefaults)
    standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *is_private = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"is_private"];

    if(!cellTitleArray)
    {
        cellTitleArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in items_array)
    {
        NSString *tcid = [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment_id"];        
        [theArray addObject:tcid];

        NSString *string;
        if(!is_private || [is_private isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"], [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }
        else
        {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }
        [cellTitleArray addObject:string];
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to tell why the last item is displayed with the value of the first?  I am really stumped!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess cellTitleArray is an instance variable? If so, the second time you call loadTitleStrings (after you add new string to remote database and get all string again), the cellTitleArray will be your currently using one. Maybe you add all strings again. If this is the situation, you can add [cellTitleArray removeAllObjects] before the foreach loop in -loadTitleStrings.

And, maybe in you second string getting some error happened. i don't think it's a good idea to do as your code:

```
items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

if(!error){
   [self loadTitleStrings];
}
```

you passed a nil to  the error parameter, and of course the error will be nil. When error happened, you just can not be informed. Try this to see if there is an error:

```
NSError *error = nil;
items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if(!error){
   [self loadTitleStrings];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```